# Scrolling Listbox Fails To Scroll items Horizontally

Tags: wpf, xaml, windows-phone-8

I have a Listbox where i am binding a list of strings to it. By default the items in the List box scroll vertically. But I want these items to scroll horizontally. Here is the piece of xaml I have.

```
<ListBox  Grid.Row="1" FontSize="25"  Name="lstitems" Height="400" 
          ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Auto"
          ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Disabled">
    <ListBox.ItemContainerStyle>
        <Style TargetType="ListBoxItem">
            <Setter Property="Padding" Value="0,15,0,0"/>
        </Style>
    </ListBox.ItemContainerStyle>
    <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
       <DataTemplate>
           <StackPanel>
                <TextBlock Name="tbl" Text="{Binding}">
                     <LineBreak></LineBreak>
                 </TextBlock>
           </StackPanel>
       </DataTemplate>
   </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
</ListBox>
```

I tried various approaches but it does not scroll horizontally. With this code I am able to move the items to the left but the rest of the items are not being loaded. The item source property is set from the cs file.

Comment: Screenshots will help to clarify. Right now I am thinking "scroll horizontally" or "elements getting arranged" vertically? Horizontal scroll bar visibility has been set to "Auto". When the text length will exceed the space confines then the horizontal scroll bar will appear. You can make it "Visible" to keep it always on. Though I am not sure if that is what you want.

Comment: I mean elements to scroll horizontally. For example lets say im displaying 10 items in the list box. In the view i want to display 5 items now when you scroll to the right i want to show the rest of 5 items and so on. Is there a way to accomplish this.

Comment: Correct me if I am wrong. You want a way to arrange items in your Listbox so that is gets displayed in say five columns of 3 rows each rather than a single column of 15 elements. 
If so then you might have to implement a custom panel and use it. Google for "WPF ArrangeOverride".

Comment: What are you binding the `Listbox` to? The example does not show any bindings for the `ItemsSource`.

Comment: Its like this I dont need any arrangement. Lets say in my list box I have total 5 items.
One

Answer (score 2):

You might try to use a WrapPanel oriented vertically.

```
<ListBox.ItemsPanel>
    <ItemsPanelTemplate>
        <WrapPanel Orientation="Vertical"/>
    </ItemsPanelTemplate>
</ListBox.ItemsPanel>
```

Also, don't forget to set `ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility` to `Auto`